# Accessing COM methods from Foxpro

Tags: dll, com, visual-foxpro, foxpro

My company is trying to use a 3rd party PDF generator from within VFoxpro 9.0. They supplied us with a .dll COM file and method documentation, but they don't support Foxpro so they can't help with this.

I registered the DLL and load the COM, and it succeeds - after I createobject() intellisense prompts me with the list of methods, so I know it is importing them correctly. But, when I try calling any of the methods I get a popup window which simply says "syntax error.", which is of very little help. I tried calling one method which takes no arguments, in case the problem was passing conventions, but that one also returns "syntax error". Is there anything more I need to do besides create an object and use it for method calls?

I am not really a foxpro guy, but I have tried this same thing using different COMs, like Excel.Application, and they work as I would expect them to. Is there any reason a COM might be incompatible with Foxpro, or require some other manipulation to get it to work?

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

---

OK, after a day and a half I found the problem.

I was typing `a=createobject("library.class")` and then `= a.method()`, and it was returning "syntax error". It turns out that if I call the variable anything but `a` it works! It appears there is some sort of bug in foxpro so that it is not parsing this correctly when the variable name is `a`. If I use `b`, `x`, `anotherName`, or anything else it works. If I type `?a` it confirms that `a` is an `(object)`, and as I said intellisense is recognizing all the method names and types. I can't wait to get back to java.

So thanks, no other answers are needed, but I will leave this up in case it can help some other poor soul.

Comment: The letters A through J are reserved in FoxPro as alternate names for the first 10 workareas. (This is a backward compatibility thing.) In general, it's a bad idea to use any of them as variable names. Ditto for the letter M, which is reserved for distinguishing variables from fields.

Comment: Hi @Russel, could you post the answer you found yourself *as an answer* and accept it, so that this question doesn't linger in the list of "unanswered questions"? And I hope you have fun back in the java world ;-)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answer I typed in above - variables cannot be called "a". Sorry for not entering it as an answer so this could be closed.

Comment: Nothings stopping you from putting the above information into an answer and accepting it.